setting WebSecurityConfig in SpringBoot app
I am setting  WebSecurityConfig in SpringBoot app.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class  WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

..
}

but I have this error Cannot resolve symbol 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter'
even I have this in the pom.xml:
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>


Since you're not setting the version to spring-boot-starter-security dependecy, it's problably using a newer version that as deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.
Check the links for more details:

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter

